# WiFi connected but no internet, ASUS laptop with Realtek 8821ae/Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 on an ASUS laptop with a Realtek 8821ae wireless card. Windows 10 is able to connect to the internet through WiFi but Ubuntu is not. Ubuntu is able to connect to WiFi networks, obtain IP addresses with DHCP, and ping routers and other hosts on the network, but does not have internet access except through ethernet. Name servers for WiFi appear to be configured correctly and match those I find listed on other connected devices and in Windows 10. Is this a driver issue or something else? Is it fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this troubleshooting guide and posts the results:

1. Start by pinging yourself , if you cant check drivers and that it is being detected.
2. Ping your gateway. if you can't check that you dont have static ip addressing from a different subnet.
3. If possible try pinging a machine in the local lan using its ip.
4. Try pinging 8.8.8.8 which is google dns server. If you can do it then you have internet access and its most likely a dns issue.
5. Finally ping www.yahoo.com , if you can do it then you should not have problem to navigate from any browser. If you cant check your dns servers
6. if pinging to www.yahoo.com works from your terminal but you cant navigate using the browser check that it doesnt have a static proxy setting.

Comment: It was a DNS issue, thanks! Switched over to 8.8.8.8 and I'm online.